# cropping of image in Windows phone 7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, imageview

[image]
I am studying for cropping of image in wp7 and developing the sample for the same.

I am able to crop an image using rectangle.

But, The problem is,

I want to resize and drag rectangle simultaneously to make cropping userfriendly.

In image as shown above rectangle can resize and drag simultaneously.